# Converting sql query to parameterized query with array in it

Tags: python, sql, postgresql

```
stmt = "UPDATE requests SET (hostname,domainname,naptrsrvptrinitial,cnameptrfinal,publiclist,privatelist) = ('%s','%s','%s','%s','{%s}','{%s}') WHERE requestid = %d"%(str(myjson['hostName']),str(myjson['domainName']),str(myjson['customRecord']),str(myjson['canName']),publicArray,privateArray,int(myjson['requestID']))
curs.execute(stmt)
```

I have above query which is subjected to sql injection, below is query which mitigate sql injection.

```
curs.execute("UPDATE requests SET (hostname,domainname,naptrsrvptrinitial,cnameptrfinal,publiclist,privatelist) = (%s,%s,%s,%s,{%s},{%s}) WHERE requestid = %s",(str(myjson['hostName']),str(myjson['domainName']),str(myjson['customRecord']),str(myjson['canName']),publicArray,privateArray,int(myjson['requestID'])))
```

if I pass array {%s} in above query it throws an error??? How do I resolve??

Comment: what language are you using?

Comment: @Pravin so ... `psycopg2`? What database client/driver? Show the **exact text of the error message** please. Also, if it's psycopg2, what version?